# Возникновение ошибки при формировании аргумента в UDF

Tags: vba

I.
Есть код:

```
Private Function GetValue(path, file, sheet, ref)
    'Выборка значения из закрытой книги'
    Dim arg As String
    'Проверка существования файла'
    If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\"
    If Dir(path & file) = "" Then
        GetValue = "Файл не найден"
        Exit Function
    End If
    'Создание аргумента'
    arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & Range(ref).Range("AI").Address(, , xlR1C1)
    'Выполнение макроса XLM'
    GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
End Function

Sub TestGetValue()
    Dim p As String, f As String
    Dim s As String, a As String
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    p = "C:\_Temp\"
    f = "002.6 Stdln Acc's.xlsm"
    s = "FOREX Acc"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For r = 1 To 100
        For c = 1 To 12
            a = Cells(r, c).Address
            Cells(r, c) = GetValue(p, f, s, a)
        Next c
    Next r
End Sub
```

После запуска возникает ошибка в строке

```
arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & Range(ref).Range("AI").Address(, , xlR1C1)
```

которая звучит так:

> Run-time Error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Поможете разобраться? Поступила рекомендация тестировать пошагово (далее см. II.)

II.
Переделал код:

```
Private Function GetValue(path, file, sheet, ref)
    'Выборка значения из закрытой книги'
    Dim arg As String
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
    'Проверка существования файла'
    If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\"
    If Dir(path & file) = "" Then
        GetValue = "Файл не найден"
        Exit Function
    End If
    Set rng1 = Range(ref)
    Set rng2 = rng1.Range("AI")
    'Создание аргумента'
    arg = rng2.Address(, , xlR1C1)
    'arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & Range(ref).Range("AI").Address(, , xlR1C1)'
    'Выполнение макроса XLM'
    GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
End Function

Sub TestGetValue()
    Dim p As String, f As String
    Dim s As String, a As String
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    p = "C:\_Temp\"
    f = "002.6 Stdln Acc's.xlsm"
    s = "FOREX Acc"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For r = 1 To 100
        For c = 1 To 12
            a = Cells(r, c).Address
            Cells(r, c) = GetValue(p, f, s, a)
        Next c
    Next r
End Sub
```

Теперь возникает ошибка:

> Run-time Error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

в строке:

```
Set rng2 = rng1.Range("AI")
```

Добавил `Dim ref as String`. Теперь возникла ошибка:

> Compile error: Duplicate declaration in current scope

в строке:

```
Dim ref as String
```

Удалил `Dim ref as String`

Исправил строку:

```
arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & Range(ref).Range("AI").Address(, , xlR1C1)
```

на строку:

```
arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & Range("AI").Address(, , xlR1C1)
```

III.
Переделан код (явно указан рабочий лист книги реципиента, куда из донора должны вставиться данные):

```
Private Function GetValue(path, file, sheet, ref)
    'Выборка значения из закрытой книги
    Dim arg As String
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
    'Проверка существования файла
    If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\"
    If Dir(path & file) = "" Then
        GetValue = "Файл не найден"
        Exit Function
    End If
    'Создание аргумента'
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Лист1")
    arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & sht.Range("AI").Address(, , xlR1C1)
    'Выполнение макроса XLM'
    GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
End Function

Sub TestGetValue()
    Dim p As String, f As String
    Dim s As String, a As String
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    p = "C:\_Temp\"
    f = "002.6 Stdln Acc's.xlsm"
    s = "FOREX Acc"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For r = 1 To 100
        For c = 1 To 12
            a = Cells(r, c).Address
            Cells(r, c) = GetValue(p, f, s, a)
        Next c
    Next r
End Sub
```

Всё равно по строке:

```
arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & sht.Range("AI").Address(, , xlR1C1)
```

возникает ошибка:

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

IV.
Код изменён (жёстко указан диапазон):

```
Private Function GetValue(path, file, sheet, ref)
    'Выборка значения из закрытой книги'
    Dim arg As String
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
    'Проверка существования файла'
    If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\"
    If Dir(path & file) = "" Then
        GetValue = "Файл не найден"
        Exit Function
    End If
    'Создание аргумента'
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Лист1")
    arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & sht.Range("a1:ai100").Address
    'Выполнение макроса XLM'
    GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
End Function

Sub TestGetValue()
    Dim p As String, f As String
    Dim s As String, a As String
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    p = "C:\_Temp\"
    f = "002.6 Stdln Acc's.xlsm"
    s = "FOREX Acc"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For r = 1 To 100
        For c = 1 To 12
            a = Cells(r, c).Address
            Cells(r, c) = GetValue(p, f, s, a)
        Next c
    Next r
End Sub
```

Теперь уже в другой строке:

```
GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
```

возникает ошибка (приложена скрином):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ошибка явно возникает во фрагменте `Range(ref).Range("AI").Address(, , xlR1C1)`. Отлаживайте его кусками. Создайте 2 переменные rng1 и rng2 типа Range и сделайте `set rng1=Range(ref) : set rng2=rng1.Range("AI") : arg=rng2.Address(, , xlR1C1)`, и смотрите, в какой точке сбой и по какой причине.

Comment: Ну вот теперь смотрите, есть ли указанном Range такой именованный диапазон. И какой смысл в первом Range, если имена диапазонов уникальны в пределах листа (или книги - зависит от установленной области)? Да и вообще, вроде бы, именованные диапазоны есть свойства книги/листа. но никак не Range. PS. Предполагалось, что после получения адреса в переменную arg следующим оператором будет до-сборка полного адреса.

Comment: Что-то запутался...

Comment: *Добавил Dim ref as String* НАФИГА? тип переменной-аргумента указывается непосредственно в определении функции.

Comment: *Что-то запутался...* Вот объясните ВАШУ логику. Вы передаёте в функцию аргумент `ref` (в который кладёте `a`, содержащий `Cells(r, c).Address`). За каким хреном в функции нужно получать `Range(ref)`, чтобы потом от него пытаться получить именованный диапазон `'AI'`? что мешает сразу обратиться к этому диапазону, минуя получение `Range(ref)`?

Comment: Дело в том, что я не понимаю, что нужно в коде поправить... Может поможете с кодом? Может переписать строку: arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & Range(ref).Range("AI").Address(, , xlR1C1) ?

Comment: Я не буду (да и никто, я полагаю, не будет) ни отлаживать Ваш код, ни даже пытаться понять Вашу (весьма непрозрачную, надо признаться) логику, в этот код заложенную. Тем более что на вопросы - даже прямые,- Вы предпочитаете не отвечать.

Comment: Дело в том, что это код из книги Уокенбах Дж. - Excel 2010. Профессиональное программирование на VBA - 2012. Мне интересен этот функционал, так как он забирает информацию из файла по указанному пути. То есть не надо ползать по проводнику и искать этот файл (при условии, что его никто не переименовал или переместил/удалил). Ну неужели код настолько непонятен, что вызывает такую агрессию? Ведь судя по всему решение где-то рядом...

Comment: Выбросите `Range(ref).` вообще нахрен пополам из кода. *это код из книги* Ошибки и опечатки никто не отменял...

Comment: Почему Вы вынуждаете меня извиняться? Ведь ресурс на то и предназначен, чтобы помогать... Я понимаю если бы я не предоставляя кода попросил решить проблему... Тогда конечно Ваши замечания правомерны. Но я же код предоставил... Даже правки вношу сам по Вашим рекомендациям... Ну что за дет сад?

Comment: Вы не желаете искать ответ на вопрос "почему именно так". Ну или озвучивать результаты своих поисков и размышлений. Вы просто констатируете "тут хрень", ждёте рекомендацию, и тупо выполняете её, не думая, почему она дана и почему именно такая. Я не вижу Вашей работы как программиста - Вы сейчас выполняете только работу тупой машинистки. Именно это и вызывает негативное отношение.

Comment: Ну я же стараюсь... Я ж новичок... Эхххх... -))) По ходу я реально не понимаю синтаксис строки arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & Range("AI").Address(, , xlR1C1). Удалил Range(ref) из строки, но ошибка всё равно на месте (Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

Comment: Ну вообще-то Range без явного указания листа берётся с активного листа. А если активен не лист, а что-то иное - возникает указанная проблема. Посему нужно получить ссылку на лист (или книгу - в зависимости от скопа диапазона), на котором находится требуемый именованный диапазон, и явно указать его, типа `Set sht=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Лист1")`, а потом `sht.Range("AI").Address(, , xlR1C1)`

Comment: А Вы в моём листинге (в теле вопроса) не имеете возможности править?

Comment: А он без файла, сам по себе, никакого смыслу не имеет. Даже не ясно, где сей код располагается - в модуле листа, формы, common-модуле или ещё где, неясно как он запускается... есть ли именованный диапазон с именем `'AI'`, где он расположен, какой скоп имеет...

Comment: Файл создался от балды, где на соответствующем листе (FOREX Acc) рандомно сгенерированы цифры в диапазоне А1:Е20. Думаю создать такой файл не представляет труда. Код располагается в модуле в файле-реципиенте (не на листе). Запускается просто: F5. Я ещё разок поменял код - САМОСТОЯТЕЛЬНО.

Comment: В коде, во фрагменте `Range("AI")`, в качестве диапазона используется имя. В книге вообще такой именованный диапазон - есть?

Comment: Нет. Такого поименнованного диапазона в книге-реципиенте нету. Поэтому сейчас в новой версии кода (IV) жёстко поставил диапазон (с запасом sht.Range("a1:ai100").Address). Пока так. Но в принципе в идеале надо считывать диапазон с файла-донора и копировать его в файл-реципиент. Но это уже другая задача (надо код конкретно переделывать). Новую ошибку в IV прописал. Может ExecuteExcel4Macro надо как-то поменять? Наверное в книге автора он ссылается точно не на мой макрос (TestGetValue). Попробовал поменять... не канает..

Answer (score 0):

**I.** В строке

```
arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & Range(ref).Range("AI").Address(, , xlR1C1)
```

в последней группе вызовов у вас какая-то каша. Вы вызываете объект `Range` от полученной ссылки, затем ищите в ней именнованный диапазон с именем "AI", от которого пытаетесь получить относительный адрес в стеле `r1c1`

**II.** В строке

```
arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & Range("AI").Address(, , xlR1C1)
```

вы полностью игнорируете полученный адрес в аргументе к функции `ref`. Сразу берете именнованный диапазон "AI" и пытаетесь получить от него адрес.

**III.** В строке

```
arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & sht.Range("AI").Address(, , xlR1C1)
```

вы делаете то же самое, только не от базового класса `Range`, а от объекта листа рабочей книги. Разницы в результате здесь не будет, так как контекст выполнения операции преобразования адреса не важен.

**IV.** В строке

```
arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & sht.Range("a1:ai100").Address
```

вы продолжаете игнорировать адрес ячейки, полученный в аргументе функции `ref`, и указываете абсолютный адрес **диапазона** ячеек, хотя исходный код тестовой процедуры явно заточен на получения адресов по каждой ячейке.

**Решение** В итоге, вам нужно было указать следующий код:

```
arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & Range(ref).Address(, , xlR1C1)
```

где преобразование адреса ведется от полученной ссылки в аргументе функции `ref`.